# Is there a way to apply the autoScale property to custom tabs made for Excel 2007 using XML?

Tags: xml, excel, vba, excel-2007, ribbon

I have made a custom tab for Excel 2007 using XML. The only issue that I have with it is that unlike the built in tabs (like "Font" or "Alignment") they don't compress when the window gets smaller resulting in tabs off the window that you have to scroll to see. I found the command `autoScale="true"` form digging around some but when I try to use it (code below) it doesn't work. Is there another way to achieve the same results in Excel 2007, possibly by incorporating VBA code (very possible since I am new to using XML), or am I just SOL?

```
<group id="Devs" label="Developer Tools" autoScale="true">
```